# Running flask application in docker container on google run, will not connect to mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have launched my flask server on google run using docker. Here is my docker file.

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim
# copy the requirements file into the image
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/


# switch working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      bzip2 \
      g++ \
      git \
      graphviz \
      libgl1-mesa-glx \
      libhdf5-dev \
      openmpi-bin \
      wget \
      python3-tk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# install the dependencies and packages in the requirements file
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# copy every content from the local file to the image
COPY . /app

# configure the container to run in an executed manner
# ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

# CMD ["app.py" ]

# Minimize image size 
RUN (apt-get autoremove -y; \
     apt-get autoclean -y)

CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8888", "app:app"]
```

it is running fine locally and on google run when I access the index page it works but any time it attempts to connect to my mongodb atlas database it is returning an error connection timeout
I have added 0.0.0.0 ip exception on my mongo side allowing access from any ip. So I have a feeling the issue is on the Google side that is somehow blocking the outbound traffic to the database.

How can I allow my server to connect to my mongo database? am I missing some type of configuration? I looked in to VPC but don't quite understand what is going on.

Here is how my url looks:
mongodb+srv://:@..mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Error I get:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 635ae8cfe34d6bf95c474b3f, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>

Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you show what your ATLAS_URI looks like?

Comment: Also please show the format of Access List Entry on Atlas

Comment: Hello I have added how the ATLAS_URI looks and the access list entry is 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

Missing an Environment variable, apparently docker automatically ignores your env file?
I added the mongo url as a env variable

Comment: Can you elaborate on the solution please, as I am venturing into new container territory? Is the ENV variable declared in the docker file?

Comment: no it is not, look in the service you are trying to launch the container. In the settings there should be option to add environment variable and values. In Google run its under the advanced section when launching the container on google run